# Where does QGIS write its error log messages?

Tags: qgis

I want to read and copypaste the error log for the crashes I am experiencing in QGIS 2.0. The error I am getting freezes QGIS so I have to ctrl-alt-del. I can see the last message in the panel, but can't copy it or scroll back to see the earlier messages. When I re-open it, the log message panel has reset to zero (QGIS starting, etc), so all the transform error messages I want are gone.

Are the older log messages written to disk somewhere?

Answer (score 46):

QGIS does not write its log messages to a file by default.

If you have a debug build (nightlies normally are) they are written to stdout. That means that if you run it in a terminal on linux you will see the messages there. On Windows I think there is a tool called Debugging Tools for Windows or similar that can intercept the messages.

An alternative is to use some minimal python scripting. Every message is emitted as a Qt signal. Therefore we can connect to these signals and write them to a file. Simply **copy the following command to your python console**

*For QGIS 3:*

```py
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

filename = '/tmp/qgis.log'

def write_log_message(message, tag, level):
    with open(filename, 'a') as logfile:
        logfile.write('{tag}({level}): {message}'.format(tag=tag, level=level, message=message))

QgsApplication.messageLog().messageReceived.connect(write_log_message)
```

---

*Or for QGIS 2:*

```py
filename = '/tmp/qgis.log'

def write_log_message(message, tag, level):
    with open(filename, 'a') as logfile:
        logfile.write('{tag}({level}): {message}'.format(tag=tag, level=level, message=message))

QgsMessageLog.instance().messageReceived.connect(write_log_message)
```

When you run this code, the output will be written to `/tmp/qgis.log`.

Comment: There should be a blank line between the end of the function definition and the final line for the Python console to be happy with the copy/paste

Comment: `NameError: name 'QgsMessageLog' is not defined`

Comment: @swiss_knight are you using QGIS 2 or QGIS3?

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn QGIS 3.28 or 3.34. [I was told](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471092) that this snippet has to be run *inside* the QGIS Python console. This was not clear when I was first reading your message as it is not *explicitly* written. But I don't see any error messages in that hand-made log file when my QGIS definitely freezes when opening a project. So I'm not able to debug it properly.

Comment: I added the import to the instructions for QGIS 3, this way it can be run from any python environment in QGIS. The error above looks very much like it's being caused by using the QGIS 2 snippet, `QgsMessageLog` is not used in the QGIS 3 version. In any case, there is no guarantee that QGIS will write something into the log in a specific moment, e.g. when freezing.

Answer (score 33):

While this won't help with this particular problem, if you just want to see the logs during runtime (i.e. QGIS is *not* crashing), you can enable the Log Messages panel.

In QGIS Go to: View>Panels>Log Messages

Make sure the box is checked.

Comment: Please read the question one more time.

Comment: How do you get back the tabs in the log messages panel if you lose a couple?

Comment: +1 as this is the correct answer. 
The comment about Stackexchange community is out of line though.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki no, the question explicitely asks persistent logs. Log messages only shows those during *this* runtime.

Answer (score 9):

Processing => Options

You need to check this : 'Keep dialog open after running an algorithm'

after that you can copy past the error log

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Might sound obvious, but I've found it useful to make the QGIS messages box a floating dialogue so that you can extend it from top to bottom of your screen. This would allow you to see and print screen more messages when QGIS crashes. Sorry, I don't know where QGIS writes these messages.