# How to find points within a polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis-2.0, point-in-polygon

I have a series of lat and long coordinates I've loaded into a spacial table (Nov01) in PostGIS, and I've created a geometry column in the table. I also have a shapefile (greatermanchester) I've loaded in with the POSTGIS 2.0 shapefile loader. I've double checked that they both have the same SRID of 4326, and then I ran the code

```
select a.*, b.*
from "Nov01" a
join greatermanchester b
on ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.geom)
limit 10
```

However it doesn't return any results.
My points table looks like:
[image]

What might I have gotten wrong?

EDIT:
There definitely should be points within the polygon. I loaded the original csv and shapefile into QGIS and got this:
[image]

I also ran explain analyze queries with these results:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE select count(*) 
from "Nov01" a 
join greatermanchester b 
on ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.geom)
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Is the `the_geom` column the geometry representation of your lat/lon columns?  If so, I would check to see if the lat/lon values got reversed when creating `the_geom`.

Comment: To elaborate on @JayCummins' suggestion: in popular parlance we say "lat-lon" but in correct GIS usage it should be "lon-lat" (i.e. x then y)

Comment: The code I used was:

SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || lon || ' ' || lat || ')',4326);

/i think this is the right way round

Comment: It looks right to me--and I've got a simulated version of your query that returns everytime.

Can you do a:

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
select a.*, b.*
from "Nov01" a
join greatermanchester b
on ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.geom)
limit 10` and post the results?`

Comment: And maybe also do a `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE
select count(*)
from "Nov01" a
join greatermanchester b
on ST_Intersects(a.the_geom, b.geom)
` (without the LIMIT).

Comment: I've updated my question with the results. I'm certain it's some sort of problem with my shapefile. I drew a simple polygon in QGIS to test and successfully ran the query against that instead of greatermanchester.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use the ST_within function and not the ST_intersect function. Here the [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html).
Here the sql code. You want only the points within greatermanchester

```
select a.*
from "Nov01" as a
join greatermanchester as b
on ST_WITHIN(a.the_geom, b.geom)
```

Comment: and maybe selecting columns explicitly will help as well:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219067/qgis-db-manager-load-new-layer-not-loading-sql-query

Comment: why `join` and not a `where` clause?

Comment: @ZachSmith the `ON` of the join clause serves the purpose of `WHERE`. `WHERE` is generally used to create a subset of something while `JOIN` is used to associate one thing with another, in this case associating points with a given polygon.

Comment: I've noticed that where also works though. Seems like it achieves the same thing (at least in my query). Is there anything to be aware of?

Comment: As we are using an inner join they produce the same result and should produce as well the same query plan (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause)