# Efficiently query two properties QGIS spatialite

Tags: sql, qgis-3, spatialite, st-intersects

I have a simple query that involves two steps:

1. non-spatial criteria (should be super-fast)
2. spatial criteria (which is really slow)

I would like to run the spatial query only on the filtered layer (which is only one polygon). Is this possible?

```
SELECT 31H.* FROM bois_corridor_forestier, 31H
WHERE bois_corridor_forestier.ID="1" /*run this first*/
AND st_intersects(bois_corridor_forestier.geometry, 31H.geometry)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query wil first combine every feature from 'bois_corridor_forestier' with '31H'.  This makes a huge intermediate-table to look for an intersection.  You better select the feature from bois_corridor_forestier you want and then do the intersection.

There are multiple ways to write the query, but for the clarity I wil do it with '[with-clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)'.

```
with selection as (select * from bois_corridor_forestier where ID = "1")

select 31H.* from 31H
right join selection on st_intersects(31H.geometry, selection.geometry)
```

Comment: This is right thing to do but also utilizing the r-tree spatial index of GeoPackage with subquery or join would probably help a lot http://erouault.blogspot.com/2017/03/dealing-with-huge-vector-geopackage.html.

Comment: `right join` is not part of QGIS set of sql queries. using `left join` instead just retreives all the features.

Comment: @user30184 Given my capacities in sql, the solution provided is much simpler and easier to implement than r-tree spatial index, which I can't figure out yet. I expect that for more complex queries, I will eventually use r-tree spatial indices, but I will put that off as long as I can.

Comment: You do not really need how it works because spatial index tables in GeoPackage are always created in the same way. Copy-pasting the SQL from the blog and editing the table names to suit with your tables is enough. In simple cases software like QGIS applies spatial indexes automatically.