# Joining each grid cells with many records in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, spatial-join, vector-grid

I have

- a grid (10 x 10 km) where each cell is identified by a code
- a shapefile, a point layer, with the year when each point was sampled

as shown in the figure below.

[image: example1]

As you can see from the image below, the year is identified by a color and in each cell I have many points of different years.

[image: example2]

What I want to obtain is an intersection between the two layers, specifically, I want the same grid with a new column showing the year(s) of the points within each cell. I show you below an example

```
Cell_ID       Year_of_sampling
10kmE275N271  2014-2015
10kmE276N271  2015
10kmE277N271  2013-2016
10kmE278N271  2013-2015-2016
```

It seems an easy task, but with `Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Intersection` is not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are trying to perform this [One-to-many spatial join with results in one row](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354187/one-to-many-spatial-join-with-results-in-one-row/354203#354203), p.s. in the query change `ST_INTERSECTS()` into `ST_WITHIN()`. Alternatively, you may be interested in this [Assigning each point name of polygon in which it lies using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283334/assigning-each-point-name-of-polygon-in-which-it-lies-using-qgis/319017#319017).

Comment: In case if you want to have only unique year than you `DISTINCT` inside of the query `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year)`

Comment: Yes, it works. I don't know why but using ST_WITHIN() it doesn't work, whereas ST_ITERSECTS() yes (and it was suitable for what I needed)

Comment: For `ST_ITERSECTS()` both are acceptable either `ST_ITERSECTS(points, grid)` or `ST_ITERSECTS(grid, points)`. When you use `ST_WITHIN()` it should be `ST_WITHIN(point, grid)` and not `ST_WITHIN(grid, point)` By `point` and `grid` I mean their geoemtries

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Field Calculator and the *array* variable to create a new field in the grid layer attribute table.

This is the expression that you should use

```
array_to_string(
array_sort(aggregate(
 layer:= 'point_layer',
 aggregate:='array_agg',
 expression:=field_name,
 filter:=contains(geometry(@parent), $geometry))),
 delimiter:='-'
 )
```

changing your `point_layer` name and your `field_name` according with your data.

in the image below an example of the result using a layer called `point` and a field called `id`.

[image]

**NB** The `array_sort` variable is not available in all the QGIS versions. To use it you should install before the plugin ArrayPlus.

Comment: Looking at your results it is what I wanted, unfortunately I hadn't the array_sort, and also I was not able to install the plugin (I use QGIS 2.18 for Mac)

Comment: Highly suggested updating it to the most recent LTD, i.e. QGIS 3.10

Comment: I agree with Taras suggestion. Anyway, array_sort order your attribute. You can always apply the expression removing the array_sort and sort the result in another way.

Comment: Shame on me should be LTR not LTD