# Join on attributes and write vector or create feature from Oracle SDO with pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, export, qgis-processing, vector-layer, sdo-geometry

QGIS 2.14 & 2.18

**Step 1 :**
I do an extraction with *QgsDataSourceURI()*

```
#get geometries
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("svdbocsva003.test.blavla.lan", "1521", "tata", "toto", "pwd")
uri.setSrid ('31370');
uri.setWkbType(QGis.WKBMutiPolygon)
uri.setDataSource("OSIRIS", "OSI_SITES" , "SHAPE",b1query ,"OBJECTID")
uri.uri()
sdoLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "requete", 'oracle')
sdoLayer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(31370))
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(sdoLayer)
sdoFeatures = sdoLayer.getFeatures()
```

All works fine until this step. The layer is added to the project **correctly**. Features are displayed.

**Step 2 :** I try to write this layer to hard disk

```
error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(sdoLayer, "C:\\user\\test\\test0.shp", "test",None, "ESRI Shapefile")
if error == QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print "success!"
else : 
    print "error"
del error
```

I get an error message. The file is written but **empty** as seen as an error has occurred.

**Step 3 :** I try to create new vector layer with joined data from oracle attributes table and the geom layer with a common field

```
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("C:\\user\\test\\test1.shp","test", fields, QGis.WKBMultiPolygon, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(31370), "ESRI Shapefile")

# add a feature
for attr in attributes :
    print(attr[0])
    exp = QgsExpression('ID_WS = {}' .format(attr[0]))
    request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
    request.setLimit(1)
    feat = QgsFeature()
    feat.setGeometry(sdoLayer.getFeatures(request).next().geometry())
    #feat.setAttributes([1, "text"])
    writer.addFeature(feat)
# delete the writer to flush features to disk
del writer
```

QGIS is crashing randomly when i iterate on attributes. OGR Logs gives me *Source de données invalide ()* (invalid data source) in the OGR logs. It looks like the problem. Sometimes it does not crash so i can note the file is empty.

---

**EDIT1** : With a workaround by activating the debugger as explained in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84790/where-does-qgis-write-its-error-log-messages), QGIS is crashing less frequently.When it's not crashing, i get a feature without geometry with a field *FID*. By the way, i had defined an output layer processing variable. It was generating error in the log. I deleted it as it was not used.
So now the only error message i get is :

```
Traitement(1): Cannot find variable: svdbocsva003 
Traitement(1): Cannot find variable: svdbocsva003
```

Where svdbocsva003  is the beginning of the host address. I don't understandwhat what is wrong.

**EDIT2 : STEP2 solved**

- The crash occurs when i want to write a file for a second time. So the overwrite is the cause. No need to be loaded in a project for crashing
- The right usage of *QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat* is with the *overrideGeometryType* as  *QgsWKBTypes.MultiPolygon* in my case and *forceMulti* as *True*. 
  With that it's generating well the vector layer

**Step 3 solved in the selected answer, my answer**

Comment: Maybe you do not have write access to root C:, maybe create "Temp" directory and try to write to it like: error = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(sdoLayer, "C:\\Temp\\test.shp", "test",None, "ESRI Shapefile")

Comment: It's for the exemple. It writes in document folder. I change the exemple path

Comment: @jlSta - In **Step 3**, is your `for` loop supposed to be indented like you have shown? Also, you have a space in the line `'ID_WS = {}' .format(attr[0])` but I would assume this would pop up an error. And maybe take `feat = QgsFeature()` outside the `for` loop.

Comment: I fixed indentation in exemple. I tested your suggestions but it does not create the layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to export to CSV with geometries as WKT

```
SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(geom)
```

In QGis, import CSV and welect the geometry column as WKT

Answer (score 3):

doesn't crash here when I use

```
feat.setGeometry(attr.geometry())
```

instead of

```
feat.setGeometry(sdoLayer.getFeatures(request).next().geometry())
```

I assume "fields" are just the columns/fields of "sdoLayer"?

Comment: Yes _fields_ is the headers of the columns. The _attributes_ on which i iterate are coming from an other source without geometry so no geometry in attributes. I use a common value to set the geometry to the corresponding feature. It's a manual join i want to do because JOIN are not allowed in the uri QGIS function.

Comment: Maybe it's your post that helped most indirectly so i give you the bounty ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your answers maybe they helped me indirectly but the code that worked for me **to join a sdo geometry layer to an oracle table/view**.
I don't know why but the joinGeombyID_WS writed as below works without crashing.

```
def joinGeombyID_WS(attributes, sdogeometry_layer) : #b1/ID_WS is the common field in sdolayer and attributes table
    joinedFeature = QgsFeature()
    exp = QgsExpression("ID_WS = '{}'".format(attributes[0]))
    request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
    request.setLimit(1)
    spatialFeature = sdogeometry_layer.getFeatures(request).next()
    geom = spatialFeature.geometry()
    joinedFeature.setGeometry(geom)
    joinedFeature.setAttributes(list(attributes))

    return joinedFeature;

def getGeoms(query) :
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection("s**********.lan", "1521", "*****", "user", "pwd")
    uri.setSrid ('31370');
    uri.setWkbType(QGis.WKBMultiPolygon)
    uri.setDataSource("Ozzy", "ozzy_SITES" , "SHAPE", query ,"OBJECTID") #add b1query
    uri.uri()
    sdoLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "requete", 'oracle')

    return sdoLayer;

def writeGeomquery(attributesList) : #b1/ID_WS is the common field in sdolayer and attributes table
    b1List =[]
    for attr in attributesList :
        b1List.append(attr[B1_column_position-1])
    sB1List = [str(b1) for b1 in b1List]
    b1Separated = ','.join(sB1List)
    b1query = "ID_WS IN (" + b1Separated + ")"

for i in range(numberOfqueriestodo):  #oracle is limited to 1000 arguments in a query
    rage = i*1000
    attributesList1000 = convertedDatesattributesList[rage:rage+1000]
    geometriesLayer = getGeoms(writeGeomquery(attributesList1000))
    for attr in attributesList1000 :
        writer.addFeature(joinGeombyID_WS(attr, geometriesLayer))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt' test it, but you can try to use this code:

```
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("C:\\user\\test\\test1.shp","test", fields, QGis.WKBMultiPolygon, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(31370), "ESRI Shapefile")

# add a feature
for attr in attributes : # if you only use 'attrs[0]', this loop is not needed
    print(attr[0])
    exp = '"ID_WS" = %s' %(attr[0])
    request = sdoLayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(exp))
    feats = [k for k in request]
    for feature in feats:
        feat = QgsFeature()
        feat.setGeometry(feature.geometry())
        #feat.setAttributes([1, "text"])
        writer.addFeature(feat)
# delete the writer to flush features to disk
del writer
```