# QGIS 2.14 - Can't read message while editing

Tags: qgis, editing

While creating a new feature (polygon), I get a blue message for some vertices but the pop-up message is just too fast for me to read or click on any pause button.

How can I set the time a message is displayed? Is there a log for all messages?

Comment: Mayby try this q/a, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84790/where-does-qgis-write-its-error-log-messages