# Message log truncated in QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image]

Does anyone know about the "Message log truncated" in running QNEAT3 plugin in QGIS? Is this an error or ...?? Actually, I don't know if it's related to QNEAT3 or not or it's an error or algorithm working in background.

I have about 11000 access point and I have also street network. I run the iso-area interpolation (from layer) and after 3 hours I got this message in log that says "Message log truncated" with red color.

Comment: Can you provide more details please?

Comment: Check out this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84790/where-does-qgis-write-its-error-log-messages)