Find cause of crash
QGIS 3.34 (LTR)
I have a QGIS project which keeps crashing. Crashes occur when editing a point layer (geopackage) or saving the Project.
How can I trace the cause of the crash - I get no error messages, the application just becomes unresponsive.

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84790/where-does-qgis-write-its-error-log-messages
